# mysql join not working as expected

Tags: mysql, join

i want to select schedule of specific teacher for a given day  ....  statement should assume that a teacher may teach in elementary and high school

here is my statement

```
 `select 
   class.name as subject_classmodel_name, 
   teachers.name as subject_teachers_name, 
   section.name as subject_section_name, 
   day.name as day_name,
   time_format(time_range.time_start,'%H:%i') as time_time_start,
   time_format(time_range.time_end,'%H:%i') as time_time_end,
   sched.subject_ref, sched.time_ref, sched.day_ref
   from schedule sched
   join class_teachers_section
   join time_range
   join day
   join class
   join teachers
   join section
   where teachers.name = "ronald manlapao" and 
   section.level = "elementary" and 
   time_range.level = "elementary" and 
   class_teachers_section.id = sched.subject_ref and 
   class.id = class_teachers_section.class_ref  and 
   teachers.id = class_teachers_section.teachers_ref and 
   section.id = class_teachers_section.section_ref and
   day.id = sched.day_ref
   order by time_range.time_start asc`
```

class_teachers_section (table) has tables class, teachers, section
schedule (table) has tables class_teachers_section, day, time_range

output

[image: output of query]

expected result

only one row (last row) with time_start (14:00) time_end (15:00) should have data in columns subject_classmodel_name, subject_teachers_name, subject_section_name, subject_ref, time_ref and day_ref. the rest should be null

Im using MYSQL 5.6.

Comment: Shouldn't you have a condition that joins the time_range with some other table?

Comment: @user16484 if i do that it will result will only show 1 row. expected result should be 5 rows. only 1 row will have all data. other 4 will have null data

Comment: You are mixing the explicit `JOIN` operator with implicit joins in the `WHERE` clause. That is a really bad idea (and any other DBMS would simply reject the invalid SQL). The condition for a `JOIN` operator needs to be defined using the `ON` keyword right after the `JOIN`. Plus: your `group by` is invalid as well (and again every other DBMS would reject the invalid statement). For details see: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/06/wrong-group-by-makes-your-queries-fragile/

Answer (score 0):

When you want only one row you have to group your data. As you are looking for infos of one day a GROUP on a date seems to do the trick. In your case GROUP BY day_name if you don't have a date field.

And when you group you can use MIN and MAX for your time: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html

Comment: it still does not show the expected results ...  result is just one row. in my example result should have 5 rows but other rows should have null values

Comment: Did i misread your statement "expected result - one row (last row) "? Do you want to have a single row (grouping) or still 5 rows but only in the newest row show the time information? (subselect should work)

I would prefer to clear the output data in your programming language than to run several subselects on the data.

Comment: 5 rows but other rows should have null data on columns subject_classmodel_name, subject_teachers_name, subject_section_name, subject_ref, time_ref and day_ref

Comment: When you do it by program (php, c++ ...) you get the last record first and remember value of time_time_start . "-" . time_time_end and check for this flag-value when you rewind to starts and print/compute your data. I presume thats the best, resource preserving way. Otherwise look for the JOIN answer from user16484 for a pure SQL solution. For myself i would work with subselects btw. with an insert into in a memory based (temp) table on which you could do a fast select with a subselect to get the data and check against the max value.